# How to access plugin output in serverless.yml of Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

*Context*: to achieve full "infrastructure as code", I want to codify the process of requesting a SSL certificate using `certbot`, validating a domain using DNS `TXT` records, uploading the certificate to Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM), and finally attaching the certificate ACM ARN to my Cloudfront distribution. This should all be done through the Serverless framework.

I saw 2 potential options to make this work.

*Option 1: use of asynchronous javascript file variables*

I.e. in `serverless.yml` I would define entries like:

```
custom:

  domains:
    prod: tommedema.tk

  ssl:
    prod:
      dnsTxtRoot: ${{file(scripts/request-cert.js):cert.dnsTxtRoot}}
      dnsTxtWww: ${{file(scripts/request-cert.js):cert.dnsTxtWww}}
      certArn: ${{file(scripts/request-cert.js):cert.certArn}}
```

Where resources would then use these variables like so:

```
- Type: TXT
  Name: _acme-challenge.www.${{self:custom.domains.${{self:provider.stage}}, ''}}
  TTL: '86400'
  ResourceRecords:
    - ${{self:custom.ssl.${{self:provider.stage}}.dnsTxtWww}}
```

Where `scripts/request-cert.js` would look like:

```
module.exports.cert = () => {
  console.log('running async logic')

  // TODO: run certbot, get DNS records, upload to ACM

  return Promise.resolve({
    dnsTxtRoot: '"LnaKMkgqlIkXXXXXXXX-7PkKvqb_wqwVnC4q0"',
    dnsTxtWww: '"c43VS-XXXXXXXXXWVBRPCXXcA"',
    certArn: 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:XXXX95:certificate/XXXXXX'
  })
}
```

The problem here is that it appears to be impossible to send parameters to `request-cert.js`, or for this script to be aware of the `serverless` or `options` plugin parameters (as it is not a plugin, but a simple script without context). This means that the script cannot be aware of the stage and domain etc. that the deployment is for, and therefore it is missing necessary variables in order to request the certificate.

So, option 1 seems out of the question.

*Option 2: create a plugin*

Of course I can create a plugin, which will have all required variables because it can access the `serverless` and `options` objects. The problem now is that I would have to access the *output* of the plugin inside `serverless.yml`, and so far I have not seen how this can be done. I.e. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
custom:

  domains:
    prod: tommedema.tk

  ssl:
    prod:
      dnsTxtRoot: ${{myPlugin:cert.dnsTxtRoot}}
      dnsTxtWww: ${{myPlugin:cert.dnsTxtWww}}
      certArn: ${{myPlugin:cert.certArn}}
```

But this does not seem possible. Is that right?

If this is also not possible, how can I achieve my purpose to programatically (i.e. following infrastructure as code principles) deploy my services with custom SSL certificates, without any manual steps? I.e.

1. request certificate from certbot
2. receive DNS txt records for validation from certbot
3. attach DNS txt records to route53 recordsets
4. deploy the DNS records and validate the certificate
5. download the certificate from certbot and upload it to ACM
6. receive the certificate ARN from ACM
7. reference to the certificate ARN from within the cloudfront distribution inside the cloudformation template
8. redeploy with the certificate ARN attached

Comment: I've now also looked at a third option, which is to use custom cloudformation resources backed by lambda. [Problem in this case appears to be that it is not possible to install dependencies or attach binaries to these lambdas](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/add-custom-resource/issues/3).

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it at deploy time, but certificates expire so it's best to make this a recurring thing.

When I was faced with this problem, I created a Lambda to upsert the SSL certificate and install it. (it needs a long timeout, but that's fine - it doesn't need to run often). The key it needs can be given as secure environment variables.

Then I use `serverless-warmup-plugin` to set up a daily trigger to check whether the certificate is due to be refreshed. The plugin is configurable to warm up relevant lambdas on deployment too, which allows me to check for expired or missing SSL certs on each deploy.

Maybe you could do something similar.

Comment: but how do you dynamically define for which environments the certificate needs to be requested and installed, and how do you dynamically create route53 recordsets based on the dns validation returned by certbot?

Comment: Via environment variables and using the AWS sdk.

Comment: I see, thanks. But this approach seems wrong to me. You are enriching resources that are part of a cloudformation stack outside of cloudformation, i.e. they are bound to become out of sync. If you were to e.g. sls remove, the cloudformation stack would be removed, but your route53 records etc. would not. This seems to violate infrastructure as code principles.

Comment: To further elaborate: resources that you create (any, including route53 recordsets) are not just supposed to be created through code, but also to be deconstructed as such. If you don't then this has a lot of consequences. For example, it would be hard to replicate and cleanup an instance of your architecture in CI processes. You wouldn't be able to do `sls deploy`, `npm test`, and then `sls remove` since your manual API calls are desyncing a part of your resources from your stack.

Comment: I'm not a purist about declarative configuration. Besides, I can add an `sls remove` hook to tell my stack to remove itself if necessary.

Comment: This may be a bit off-topic, but would an upsert of a recordset require replacement? I can't imagine changing any of the pieces that would without a full redeploy so updating externally shouldn't break sls deploy/remove.

Comment: It's more like installing the new cert then switching to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) would be the best choice for this particular use case. Since you have 3 distinct steps, they would be three seperate Lambda functions that Step Functions can pass inputs/outputs between as well as including wait times and retries.